# How to use bit operations in mysql?

Tags: mysql, bitwise-operators

I'm trying to get xor result:

```
SELECT '12e627593dbc2307' ^ '12d2552c66ddc94b';
```

Or when I have table with hex inside `hash` column:

```
SELECT hash ^ '12d2552c66ddc94b';
```

But MySQL says - 0.

How can I get correct result? What to do if I have hex inside VARCHAR (string)?

Answer (score 0):

If those strings are supposed to be hex digits, you need to prefix with `X`:

```
SELECT X'12e627593dbc2307' ^ X'12d2552c66ddc94b';
```

When run in MySQL workbench, that gives:

```
'14762547158837836'
```

The result is shown in decimal.  That corresponds to X'3472755B61EA4C', which I believe is the answer you were looking for.

Answer (score -1):

Solution:

```
SELECT CONV('12e627593dbc2307', 16, 10) ^ 0x12d2552c66ddc94b
```

OR

```
SELECT CONV(hash, 16, 10) ^ 0x12d2552c66ddc94b
```

Comment: Could you please elaborate as to why this is a solution to the asker's question?

Comment: I've posted a bit wrong question.. I want to know what to do if I have HEX inside string